# MVVM in Swift - ViewModel properties that do not have a value in the model

Tags: swift, mvvm

I've a view model with properties that works fine - for example:

```
struct ViewModel {
    let Names: [String]
    let attributedString: NSAttributedString
    let textAlignment: NSTextAlignment
}
```

When I run this on "Model A" everything works fine because when I return the ViewModel I have all the inputs. Model code example:

```
return ViewModel(Names: Names, attributedString: attributedText, textAlignment: .left)
```

What if I wanted to put a property in the ViewModel that will not contain data for the return in the model?  For example if I wanted to add the property "address" to the ViewModel but not all the models I had contained that info? The return on the Model page throws up an error.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of error is thrown? 
But I think you should mark address property as [Optional](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) value. Something like:

```
struct Model {
    let name: String
    let address: String?

    init(name: String, address: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
    }
}

let modelA = Model(name: "abc", address: "abc") // Model
let modelB = Model(name: "abc") // Model
```